# Numbers between $1$ and $1000$ (even/between 100 & 200/ends with 5 or 6) - Combination Theory

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I have the following problem:

> Calculate how many numbers between $1$ and $1000$, inclusive, are even, or are between $100$ and $200$ or ends with $5$ or with $6$.

But I am confused with the wording of the problem as it seems there are many *conditional conditions*. Can anyone assist me in understanding the problem and how to solve it or is is there really a problem with the instructions?

Comment: @fleablood Sorry for that, error in translation. I made the corrections.

Comment: This is a good time to use [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  Let $E$ be the set of **e**ven numbers between $1$ and $1000$.  Let $B$ be the set of numbers **b**etween $100$ and $200$.  Let $D$ be the set of numbers between $1$ and $1000$ which en**d** with a $5$ or with a $6$.  You are asked to calculate $|E\cup B\cup D|$.

Comment: To continue, inclusion-exclusion expands the above to be $|E|+|B|+|D|-|E\cap B|-|E\cap D|-|B\cap D|+|E\cap B\cap D|$, each of these terms should be much easier to manage, for example $|B\cap D|$ counts the number of numbers between $100$ and $200$ which ends in a $5$ or a $6$, i.e. $B\cap D=\{105,106,115,116,125,126,\dots,196\}$ which can be counted by hand or you can spot the pattern.

Comment: @JMoravitz But for example; the numbers between $1$ and $1000$ that end with a $5$ or a $6$, how do I know how much of them there are?

Comment: @JMoravitz Now I see. Could you post it all as an answer?

Comment: use your [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  They will all be three digit integers which end in a $5$ or a $6$.  Pick whether it ends in a five or a six.  Pick what the hundred's digit is.  Pick what the ten's digit is.

Comment: Numbers either end in $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$.  How many end in each?

Comment: I suggest you to study Inclusion-Exclusion Principle because you keep asking questions which can be solved using Inclusion-Exclusion Principle for few days and before asking a new question without any attempt, you should try using the principle. If you have trouble using it after studying and making some attempts, then just ask but this does not seem to be the case as I observed.

Comment: @ArsenBerk I am currently studying in a foreign country where one of their main focus is Mathematics and the studients would have already studied the basic concepts at a lower level which I did not have and to make matters worse, it has been over 6 years since I've studied Mathematics. So you tell me!

Comment: Oh, don't misunderstand me I am not complaining or saying anything about the questions or they way you are asking. That was just a suggestion. I am pretty sure that people here, including me, can try to help you anytime but if you don't try to use the things that you learn here in later questions for example, then is there a meaning people here answering them? While answering a question, whoever answers it also learns something but the main purpose is showing you the way.

Comment: @ArsenBerk I fully get you but for me most of the problems might require similar applications but since Math is not my strong point and to me the questions don't appear that way so it's sorts like I'm in pre-school again.

Comment: Well, I understand it. Then I will also try to be more clear than I was before if I coincide one of your questions. I apologize if my language was harsh or I unintentionally said something wrong.

Comment: @ArsenBerk No, no worries. All that is part of the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer simpler questions first.

i) How many numbers are there between $1$ and $1000$ total?

ii) How many of them are odd?  How many are even? How many are neither?  How many are both?

iii) How many end with $6$?  How many do not end in $6$.

iv) How many end with $5$?  How many do not end in $5$?

v) How many end with either $5$ or with $6$.

vi) How many that end with $5$ are even?  How many that end with $6$ are even?  How many that end with $5$ are not even? How many that end with $6$ are not even?

vii) If you take all the numbers that are even and all the numbers that end with $5$ and all the numbers that end in $6$ how many numbers total would that be?

Can you answer those questions?  If not where do you run into trouble?

P.S.  I forgot to ask about between $100$ and $200$.  But... same idea.  Just think this out slowly.  It's hard to answer as it's hard to know where your difficulty lies.

Others have mentioned Inclusion-Exclusion principal that will *certainly* help you in the future. But I think you need to simply figure this out *slowly* on your own.

Comment: I think that I should be able to solve it now. Thx. Is just that I did not interpret it like this.